# Marks on my Macbook Pro Retina's Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, scratches

I was cleaning my macbook pro retina's display with Apple's piece of cleaning cloth that came with the macbook in box.

But after I'm done cleaning I noticed weird marks on my screen and they won't be removed with cleaning liquids or even with pressure.

they looks like if the black color of the screen frame was scratched .. but is that even possible ? since its already has a glass layer above it ?!

So anyone know how are those marks appeared ? and how to remove them if possible ?

[image]

[image]

I hope the images are clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the **exact** same thing happening to my retina MacBook Pro. I carried in my MacBook Pro recently to an authorised service provider. As per the technician, this happens due to scratching of the Anti Glare coating. I was covered under Apple Care and got the screen replaced, which apparently is the only way to get rid of the marks.

Comment: I guess I have to live with that because in my country there is no Apple Care program and replacing my screen in authorised service center would costs alot :/ ... Thanks for your answer ^_^

Comment: Yes, you are right. It costs a lot of money and I wouldn't have been able to justify the price if not for Apple Care. On another note, Apple Care should be available in your country irrespective of where there's an Apple Retail store. It is highly recommended and I suggest you get it if you are still covered under original warranty. For details read [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202702).